# Is there an analytical solution to the following integral:

Tags: calculus

Is there a nice solution to this integral:
$$\int\frac{-a^2 da} {C^2 \sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{C^2}}}$$

Comment: You can use the trigonometric substitution $a = C \sin{\theta}$, $da = C \cos{\theta} \, d\theta$. However, you need to have limits of integration because your integrand is not defined for all values of $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For integrals you can always go to [wolfram|alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bc%5E-2%20a%5E2/Sqrt%5B1%20-%20a%5E2/c%5E2%5D,%20a%5D) and they'll tell you what to do. The solution is

$$\frac{1}{2} \left(-a \sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{c^2}}+c \text{ArcSin}\left[\frac{a}{c}\right]\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Take $a=C\sin(\theta)$ so your integral became: $$\frac{-1}{C}\int \sin^2(\theta)d\theta$$ which is elementary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You should try some trigonometric substitution (or install sympy, then can you answer by yourself. A related (simplified= integral:

```
In [3]: integrate( x**2/sqrt(1-x**2), x)
Out[3]: 
       ⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽          
      ╱    2               
  x⋅╲╱  - x  + 1    asin(x)
- ─────────────── + ───────
         2             2   

In [4]:
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. To solve it you need to do a trig substitution.

Answer (score 1):

## Hint

Try substitution $a=C\sin{t}$